# How to Send key faster with PixelGetColor / PixelSearch

Tags: autohotkey, sendinput

I am using this code to send pot key when I press skill key

```
*RButton::
{
    PixelGetColor, ColorOutPut, 256, 762, Fast RGB  ;2 last
    if (ColorOutPut =  0x090606)
    {
        ;~ PixelGetColor, ColorOutPut, 273, 750, Fast RGB   ;charge
        ;~ if not (ColorOutPut =  0x3A3436)
        ;~ {
            SetKeyDelay -1,-1
            Sendinput {Blind}{2 down} 
            SetKeyDelay -1,-1
            Sendinput {Blind}{2 up} 
            ;~ }
    }
    SetKeyDelay -1,-1
    SendInput, {Blind}{RButton DownR}
}
return
*RButton up::
SetKeyDelay -1,-1
SendInput, {Blind}{RButton up}
return
```

PixelGetColor run time is 0.1-0.2 sec for me so skill is being late that time, because of it i can't send multiple PixelGetColor.
What I want to ask is how can I read color and send keys instantly and that way my skill won't be late?
And I cant send skill forward because skill gets help from pots. Thx for you support.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to add 'Process, Priority,, High'.   The -1/-1 are not ideal to use, most people use 'SetKeyDelay, 0'